# catch(...) swallowing all other catches in xcode llvm 3.0

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, llvm, clang++

I'm trying to get googletest to run on my c++ project, and part of this involves using `EXPECT_THROW(statement, expected_exception);`. I'm using XCode with the "Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0" selected. All this is on Snow Leopard 10.6.8, XCode 4.2.

I could not get any of these tests to pass, even when using the explicit dummy case `EXPECT_THROW(throw std::runtime_error(), std::runtime_error);`

After expanding the macro (from gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:1114 GTEST_TEST_THROW_)  myself to

```
    bool gtest_caught_expected = false;
    try {
        // GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_(statement);
        throw std::runtime_error("sigh");
    }
    // catch (expected_exception const&) {
    catch (std::runtime_error const& e){
        std::cout << "const ref caught" << std::endl;
        gtest_caught_expected = true;
    }
    // added by me to check it wasn't a const& issue
    catch (std::runtime_error e){
        std::cout << "type caught" << std::endl;
        gtest_caught_expected = true;
    }
    catch (...) {
        //gtest_msg.value =
        // "Expected: " #statement " throws an exception of type "
        //#expected_exception ".\n  Actual: it throws a different type.";
        //goto GTEST_CONCAT_TOKEN_(gtest_label_testthrow_, __LINE__);
        std::cout << "unknown caught" << std::endl;         
    }
```

then setting a break point in gdb with `catch catch` and stepping through, I can see that the `catch(runtime_errors)` are skipped, and the `catch(...)` is being executed. If I comment out the `catch(...)` block then the correct `catch(std::runtime_error const& e)` statement is executed.

Setting my compiler to "LLVM GCC 4.2" fixes the issue but I want to target clang++.

My separate EXPECT_THROW test case works when compiled manually with clang++ on the command line so I figure it must be some esoteric xcode or llvm setting? Or maybe some how LLVM is monkey wrenching my runtime_error into some other type? I tried a `catch throw` but could get any type information in that context.

Anyone experienced this before or have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

So I was also linking with libprofile_rt.dylib, along with the compiler flags `-fprofile-arcs -fprofile-coverage`. Removing the compiler flag `-fprofile-arcs` removed the issue. Annyoing because it breaks my coverage reports.

(Linking with librpofile_rt.a had the same issues)

Surely I'm not the only one to see this since LLVM supposedly uses googletest for their testcases?!

*Unsure if I should post this as the answer or if someone more knowledgable may come along and provide a real solution.*

Comment: Not the answer, but you should generally catch by non-const reference, not by const reference or value.

Comment: You might want to try a newer version of clang; there have been some significant fixes for exception handling since Apple LLVM compiler 3.0.

Comment: Yeah, it's tempting to go down the self built path but not so good for integrating with a team unless everyone is ready to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After waiting a bit it looks like there isn't a known fix for this so I'll post my answer as above. It might be fixed in Xcode 4.3*

So I was also linking with libprofile_rt.dylib, along with the compiler flags -fprofile-arcs -fprofile-coverage. Removing the compiler flag -fprofile-arcs removed the issue. Annyoing because it breaks my coverage reports.

(Linking with librpofile_rt.a had the same issues)

Surely I'm not the only one to see this since LLVM supposedly uses googletest for their testcases?!